# Groovy script is giving error in SoapUI

Tags: soap, groovy

i am writing groovy script in SoapUI, while writing below mentioned code i am getting error like "No Such propety:GetSupplierByCityResult for class:Script1".

SoapUI resonse:

```
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"  
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<soap:Body>
  <GetSupplierByCityResponse xmlns="http://www.webservicex.net/">
     <GetSupplierByCityResult>false</GetSupplierByCityResult>
     <SupplierDataLists>
        <SupplierDatas/>
        <TotalRecords>0</TotalRecords>
     </SupplierDataLists>
  </GetSupplierByCityResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Groovy code:

```
//Define Groovy Utils and holder for validating the XML reponse content

 def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(messageExchange.responseContent)

   //Define the NameSpace
   holder.namespaces["ns"] = "http://www.webservicex.net"

   //Get the Value of the Node 'GetReservationRSResult' and assign to a       variable
   def GetReservationResponse =   holder.getNodeValue("//GetSupplierByCityResult")

   //print the value of the GetReservationResponse
   log.info "The GetReservationResponse " + GetReservationResponse

    //Comparing the value to print 'Pass' or 'Fail'
    if(GetSupplierByCityResult=="false")
  { log.info "Pass" }
   else
   { log.info "fail"}
```

---

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line:

```
if(GetSupplierByCityResult=="false")
```

Your variable is called `GetReservationResponse` isn't it?

Looks that way from the line:

```
def GetReservationResponse =   holder.getNodeValue("//GetSupplierByCityResult")
```

Variables also should start with lower-case characters (it's a good convention to follow as otherwise Groovy might guess you're talking about a class when you come up with a poorly named variable)

Comment: Thank you tim_yates for your support, now it is working fine.